# Javascript convert current time to timeago

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to convert the current time to timeago like facebook and twitter have (2 min ago, 30sec ago). For that, I am taking the current time and with the help of function converting it to approx time. The code is below:

```js
var current = new Date();
console.log(timeDifference(current, new Date(2018, 03, 27, 10, 30, 00, 00)));
console.log(timeDifference(current, new Date(2018, 03, 27, 10, 00, 00, 00)));

function timeDifference(current, previous) {

  var msPerMinute = 60 * 1000;
  var msPerHour = msPerMinute * 60;
  var msPerDay = msPerHour * 24;
  var msPerMonth = msPerDay * 30;
  var msPerYear = msPerDay * 365;

  var elapsed = current - previous;

  if (elapsed < msPerMinute) {
    return Math.round(elapsed / 1000) + ' seconds ago';
  } else if (elapsed < msPerHour) {
    return Math.round(elapsed / msPerMinute) + ' minutes ago';
  } else if (elapsed < msPerDay) {
    return Math.round(elapsed / msPerHour) + ' hours ago';
  } else if (elapsed < msPerMonth) {
    return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerDay) + ' days ago';
  } else if (elapsed < msPerYear) {
    return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerMonth) + ' months ago';
  } else {
    return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerYear) + ' years ago';
  }
}
```

But, it is not working correctly and I can't seem to know why?

Comment: State what you expected and what happened instead.

Comment: @H.B. it is giving me alert `-2667427 seconds ago` instead it should give me time in hours ago.

Comment: Month starts with 0.

Comment: take a look at https://momentjs.com/ "Relative Time"

Answer (score 6):

Your month is off by one (0 based). (May still return wrong result based on time zones of course.)

```js
var current = new Date();
console.log(timeDifference(current, new Date(2018, 02, 27, 10, 30, 00, 00)));
console.log(timeDifference(current, new Date(2018, 02, 27, 10, 00, 00, 00)));

function timeDifference(current, previous) {

  var msPerMinute = 60 * 1000;
  var msPerHour = msPerMinute * 60;
  var msPerDay = msPerHour * 24;
  var msPerMonth = msPerDay * 30;
  var msPerYear = msPerDay * 365;

  var elapsed = current - previous;

  if (elapsed < msPerMinute) {
    return Math.round(elapsed / 1000) + ' seconds ago';
  } else if (elapsed < msPerHour) {
    return Math.round(elapsed / msPerMinute) + ' minutes ago';
  } else if (elapsed < msPerDay) {
    return Math.round(elapsed / msPerHour) + ' hours ago';
  } else if (elapsed < msPerMonth) {
    return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerDay) + ' days ago';
  } else if (elapsed < msPerYear) {
    return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerMonth) + ' months ago';
  } else {
    return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerYear) + ' years ago';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your tests as month starts with 0. Change

```
console.log(timeDifference(current, new Date(2018, 03, 27, 10, 30, 00, 00)));
console.log(timeDifference(current, new Date(2018, 03, 27, 10, 00, 00, 00)));
```

to

```
console.log(timeDifference(current, new Date(2018, 02, 27, 10, 30, 00, 00)));
console.log(timeDifference(current, new Date(2018, 02, 27, 10, 00, 00, 00)));
```

and your code works fine.